# Undoing a recursion tree

Tags: c++, optimization, recursion, memoization

**SHORT** How should I reduce (optimize) the number of needed operations in my code?

**LONGER** For research, I programmed a set of a equations in C++ to output a sequence if it fits the model. On the very inside of the code is this function, called MANY times during run-time:

```
int Weight(int i, int q, int d){
    int j, sum = 0;
    if (i <= 0)
        return 0;
    else if (i == 1)
        return 1;
    for (j = 1; j <= d; j++){
        sum += Weight((i - j), q, d);
    }
    sum = 1 + ((q - 1) * sum);
    return sum;
}
```

So based on the size of variable `d`, the size of the index `i`, and how many times this function is called in the rest of the code, many redundant calculations are done. How should I go about reducing the number of calculations?

Ideally, for example, after `Weight(5, 3, 1)` is calculated, how would I tell the computer to substitute in its value rather than recalculate its value when I call for `Weight(6, 3, 1)`, given that the function is defined recursively?

Would multidimensional vectors work in this case to store the values? Should I just print the values to a file to be read off? I have yet to encounter an overflow with the input sizes I'm giving it, but would a tail-recursion help optimize it?

Note: I am still learning how to program, and I'm amazed I was even able to get the model right in the first place.

Comment: Are you familiar with dynamic programming or memoization?

Comment: @templatetypedef I have heard of dynamic programming many times, but still unsure on what it means. From what it looks like, memoization is a popular answer and could just be a lookup table, so that's what I'm gonna try first.

Answer (score 3):

You may use memoization

```
int WeightImpl(int i, int q, int d); // forward declaration

// Use memoization and use `WeightImpl` for the real computation
int Weight(int i, int q, int d){
    static std::map<std::tuple<int, int, int>, int> memo;

    auto it = memo.find(std::make_tuple(i, q, d));
    if (it != memo.end()) {
        return it->second;
    }
    const int res = WeightImpl(i, q, d);
    memo[std::make_tuple(i, q, d)] = res;
    return res;
}

// Do the real computation
int WeightImpl(int i, int q, int d){
    int j, sum = 0;
    if (i <= 0)
        return 0;
    else if (i == 1)
        return 1;
    for (j = 1; j <= d; j++){
        sum += Weight((i - j), q, d); // Call the memoize version to save intermediate result
    }
    sum = 1 + ((q - 1) * sum);
    return sum;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/663sZE)

Note: As you use recursive call, you have to be cautious with which version to call to really memoize each intermediate computation. I mean that the recursive function should be modified to not call itself but the memoize version of the function. For non-recursive function, memoization can be done without modification of the real function.

Comment: It should be noted that a `std::map` may be replaced by a more efficient data structure depending on the problem. But it certainly a good simple way of determining if it's actually worth spending time on that approach.

Comment: @stefan I copied and pasted your code but a few errors pop up. Notably, "memo is undefined" " 'it' cannot be used before it is initialized" and "left of '.end' must have class/struct/union." I greatly appreciate the effort you put into helping me, though so far! Before I copied and pasted, I tried my hand at memoization and just stored the weights in a global array, which improved the calc speed by about 10%.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store the intermediate values. For example, for certain d and q have an array that contains the value of Weight(i, q, d) at index i.

If you initialize the array items at -1 you can then do in your function for example

```
if(sum_array[i] != -1){    // if the value is pre-calculated
    sum += sum_array[i];
}
else{
    sum += Weight((i - j), q, d);
}
```